# Azure toolkit for Intellij - Templates missing in Azure Function Class

Tags: intellij-idea, azure-functions, azure-functions-core-tools

I am trying to use Azure Function class to generate a template for AzureQueueTrigger function in IntelliJ. However, when I click on the package -> new -> Azure Function Class:
[image]

I see templates for only three types of triggers:

[image]

Blob trigger and Queue trigger options are missing. However when I create a new project, I see all the 5 trigger options for azure functions.
[image]

Any one else is facing this issue?  Kindly let me know if any one has found a solution (to see all the 5 options to add the desired template in an existing project) for this issue?

My environment:
Windows 11
IntelliJ IDEA 2022.3.1 (Community Edition)
Azure toolkit plugin version: 3.73.0-2022.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been fixed in the latest version [**3.74.1-2022.3**] of Azure Toolkit plugin

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In IntelliJ IDE, I have experienced the Same that cannot see more than 3 types of Triggers when adding the additional Azure Function Class to the Java Azure Functions Project but can be able to see most of the trigger types in IntelliJ IDE.

For the temporary workaround/fix, you can use VS Code where I experienced same but able to see all types of triggers and add them to existing Java Azure Functions Projects by using template filter field:

[image]
Regarding the IntelliJ IDE Issue, I have raised a ticket #[105223](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/105223) in the official Issues Tracking GitHub Repository of the Azure Java Functions Project - IntelliJ IDE Development.